# Error of Maclaurin series

Tags: calculus

Estimate the error if the Maclaurin polynomial of degree $5$ for $\sin(x)$ is used to approximate $\sin(0.2)$

I assume I can use the series-representation of $\sin(x)$, but i'm not sure how to estimate the error. Is there a standard method of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

In an alternating series, the error is bounded by the first neglected term. So, in your case, I suppose it is $\frac{x^7}{5040}$.

Comment: Won't the answer, using the Lagrange Remainder, be ![l](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Cfrac%7B0.2%5E%7B6%7D%7D%7B6%21%7D)